# How to pass a variable from c++ to java in ndk

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a java method :

```
    public native String getMessage();
```

In my c++ file, that is :

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL JNIFUNCTION_NATIVE(getMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jstring mystring));


};

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL JNIFUNCTION_NATIVE(getMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj,jstring mystring)){
           return env->NewStringUTF( mystring);

        }
```

Another method is :

```
void thebest(){

char* myxxx="test word";
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL JNIFUNCTION_NATIVE(getMessage(null,null,myxxx));


}
```

But it doesn't work (for passing `myxxx` into `getMessage`)

What is the problem?

Comment: i try it.i can pass string from c++ to java .but one time and one value.but i need to call it every in code

Comment: Maybe you could use a native method that returns an array. In the C++ code you'd use JNI to create and populate the Java array.

Comment: Do you have any sample for it?